# Get processed CSS paths in JavaScript/CoffeeScript [OBSOLETE]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

To work around a webfont issue, I need to load one CSS with JS instead of linking it on the page. The JS needs the URL to the CSS which is no problem on production where all assets are precompiled during deployment.

In development, however, I don't really want to precompile all assets just to get that one static URL working. Is there a way to access an object which contains the CSS-paths (after the asset pipeline has converted them from SASS) in a JS/CS file?

I'm assuming that the asset pipeline deals with CSS/SASS before it deals with JS/CS which may or may not be the case.

Thanks!!

Comment: We found another solution for the underlying problem, so no need for this anymore. (It would have been an ugly hack anyways.)

Answer (score 0):

if you specify as below in application.css assuming whattever.css be the css you are trying to link in javascript.

```
 //= require whatever.css
```

Then in the view or layout in development mode a link to css will be generated something like this below.

```
   <link href="/assets/whatever.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and I assume there should be no problem in accessing the .css from javascript

For more info see this link. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development

Comment: That's the standard and I'm well aware of all this. However, my problem is that the CSS with the webfonts has to be loaded from JS rather than with a link on the page, to make sure, domready fires only after all webfonts have downloaded.